# c# convert days to hh:mm in timespan

Tags: c#

while calculate the sum of all span it shows result in days`(dd:HH:mm)`.question is how i get the sum only in `HH:mm` format.how i convert the days in hour

```
          TimeSpan Span1 = TimeSpan.Parse(mnts1);
          TimeSpan Span2 = TimeSpan.Parse(tuts1);
          TimeSpan Span3 = TimeSpan.Parse(wdts1);
          TimeSpan Span4 = TimeSpan.Parse(thts1);
          TimeSpan Span5 = TimeSpan.Parse(frts1);
          TimeSpan Span6 = TimeSpan.Parse(stts1);
          TimeSpan Span7 = TimeSpan.Parse(suts1);
          TimeSpan  rf = Span1 + Span2 + Span3 + Span4 + Span5 + Span6 + Span7;
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be a format option for getting the total hours out of a `TimeSpan`. Your best bet would be to use the [`TotalHours`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.totalhours%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) property instead:

```
Console.WriteLine("{0:00}:{1:00}", (int)rf.TotalHours, rf.Minutes);
```

`TotalHours` returns a double as it includes the fractional hours so you need to truncate it to just the integer part.

Comment: why would you have to cast to an integer?  Your format code specifies that decimals should not be shown.

Comment: @Mitch Just to make the user aware that it returns `double`..nothing more than that.

Comment: @bhushan..it get the total hour..but i find is right ans. thanks                                                                  string hr1 = rf.TotalHours.ToString("00") + ':' + rf.Minutes.ToString();

Comment: Actually `(int)` is important. Otherwise 11:45 would be displayed as 12:45 since TotalHours=11.75 gets rounded to 12.